# I can't use the library react-native-image-header-scroll-view

Tags: react-native

type error
"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports"

I followed the instructions but it doesn't seem to work

here is my code

```
import HeaderImageScrollView from 'react-native-image-header-scroll-view';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const MIN_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 90 : 55;
const MAX_HEIGHT = 400;

const ProductDetailImage = () => {
  
  return (
    <View>
      <HeaderImageScrollView
        maxHeight={MAX_HEIGHT}
        minHeight={MIN_HEIGHT}
        maxOverlayOpacity={0.6}
        minOverlayOpacity={0.3}
        ScrollViewComponent={FlatList}
        data={product.image}
        renderHeader={({item, index}) => (
          <Image source={item} />
        )}></HeaderImageScrollView>
    </View>
```

[I have followed this with no success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67915520/please-help-react-native-image-header-scroll-view)

Comment: According to the doc from [react-native-image-header-scroll-view](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-header-scroll-view), you should change your import to `import { ImageHeaderScrollView } from 'react-native-image-header-scroll-view'; `

Comment: thank you. I have had success using your method

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to `export` your component:

```js
export default ProductDetailImage;
```